# il me faut le faire (why not "de le faire")

Tags: grammaire, infinitif

Is there a general overarching principle why we write:

```
il me faut le faire
```

instead of:

```
il me faut de le faire
```

or is this a case of an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grammatical rule is il faut + infinitive verb.

In your example, *Il me faut le faire* uses *faire* as a complementary infinitive (l'infinitif complément) of another verb, *il faut*.  ***Il faut* (verbe *falloir*) takes the infinitive** **without a preposition** to express "It is necessary (for me) to do (it)."

This is not an exception; *il faut* does not take a preposition before the infinitive.

If the subject changes for emphasis/style, you can use *il faut* with *que* (relative pronoun, not a preposition) followed by the subjunctive.  That would rephrase your sentence to *Il faut que je le fasse,* but this would change the register. Using the infinitive helps avoid the subjunctive in this way, but it's more common/colloquial in speaking to use the subjunctive for such a short expression than the complementary infinitive with the pronouns.  I would expect to see that more in writing.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il%20me%20faut%20le%20faire%2C%20faut%20que%20je%20le%20fasse&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20me%20faut%20le%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfaut%20que%20je%20le%20fasse%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20me%20faut%20le%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfaut%20que%20je%20le%20fasse%3B%2Cc0) shows how much more common it is to say "il faut que je le fasse," but that doesn't change the grammatical rule of il faut + infinitive without a preposition.

Some other verbs that work this way like *valoir*, *aller*, *devoir*, *aimer* followed by an infinitive are given [here](https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-infinitifs-complements-dun-autre-verbe/#Verbes-construits-sansprposition) as well as a list of some verbs that do take a preposition.

Comment: Nice answer. I heard more "il me faut +inf" than the subjunctive form when I lived in South Eastern France close to Nîmes. I believe it's a regional feature.

Comment: [Ngrams "Il me faut le faire" vs "il faut que je le"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+me+faut+le+faire%2Cil+faut+que+je+le&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) est encore plus fort.