# Est-ce que je devrais utiliser le subjonctif passé pour cette phrase?

Tags: grammaire

Je veux traduire:

> *I needed to reread the page multiple times*

Est-ce qu'il vaut mieux dire :

> 1. Il fallait que j'aie relu la page plusieurs fois

ou ces autres options sont elles aussi bonnes :

> 2. Il fallait que je relise...
> 3. Je devais relire...
> 4. J'ai du relire...

Je n'arrive pas a comprendre s'il y a une différence de sens entre elles!

Comment: La suite de la phrase ou le contexte peut avoir de l'important pour savoir quelle tournure utilisée

Answer (score 4):

La première phrase ne marche pas vraiment.

La deuxième et la troisième sont correctes mais leur sens peut être légèrement différent de l'anglais.

La quatrième traduit convenablement l'anglais *I had to reread the sentence multiple times*.

Je proposerais aussi les phrases suivantes :

> ***Il m'a fallu relire la page plusieurs fois**.* (plus soutenu/littéraire)
> ***Il a fallu que je relise la page plusieurs fois**.*
> ***J'ai eu besoin de relire la page plusieurs fois**.*

Ces trois dernières phrases postulent que la relecture a bien eu lieu, ce qui n'est pas impliqué par ***Il fallait que...*** ou ***Je devais...*** qui peuvent tous deux être suivis de « **mais je ne l'ai pas fait** » (*but I didn't do it*).

Comment: Peux-tu préciser quel(s) élément(s) contribuent au ton soutenu dans « Il m'a fallu relire ... » ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak ***Il me faut + infinitif*** me semble toujours plus soutenu/littéraire que ***Il faut que je + verbe conjugué***. Il n'est cependant pas "trop soutenu" et présente aussi un avantage certain en terme de simplicité de conjugaison, ce qui fait qu'il est peut-être plus courant chez les apprenants que chez les francophones natifs.

Comment: @LukeSawczak See https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43815/1109